# Spark Streaming Real Time Processing

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I need an application that enables the communication between workers. Let's say worker 1 is working on job 1 and it will generate a data output on which other works rely on. Besides, this process should be repeated for many times, meaning that every time a new data set generated by worker 1, other workers should start inputing this data set and doing their jobs. Can spark do this? So far I have seen spark streaming real time processing, but the streaming communication seems not happen between workers? Any direction or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you're looking for something like Akka

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the required operations one after the another in 1 single Spark Streaming Job.

Though I haven't tried but you can also try using some workflow components like Oozie to configure your standard Spark Batch Jobs (Not Streaming).

Recently Spring XD also introduced integration with Spark Jobs. That may also work - http://www.slideshare.net/mark_fisher/spark-meets-spring.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.json4s.jackson.Json;

public class lotWeather {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin-master");
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkStreamingMessageListener").master("local").getOrCreate();
    enter code here
        StructType weatherType= new StructType().add("quarter","String").add("heatType", "string").add("heat","integer")
                .add("windType","string").add("wind","integer");

        Dataset<Row> rawData = sparkSession.readStream().schema(weatherType).option("sep", ",")
                .csv("C:\\Users\\sorun\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\bigdata\\sparkstreaming\\*");

        Dataset<Row> heatData = rawData.select("quarter", "heat").where("heat>29");


        StreamingQuery start = heatData.writeStream().outputMode("append").format("console").start();
        start.awaitTermination();




    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation along with code is generally helpful for the OP

Comment: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3hxBBxJH6C/)               link to error